# FOSUser Bundle - Prevent Disabled users from logging in

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have created a loginsuccesshandler.php and am checking if the user is !enabled like this

```
  public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {

            $user = $token->getUser();
            if(!$user->isEnabled())
            {//do not pass go

                $request->getSession()->invalidate();
                $this->security->setToken(null);
               //$token->setToken(null);
                return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('account_disabled'));
            }
```

This line

```
 $request->getSession()->invalidate();
```

is causing the following error:

```
Warning: SessionHandler::write(): Parent session handler is not open in /var/www...
```

But I cant remove it because if the user clicks the remember me checkbox, they will still be logged in.

I had the same problem with FOS logging out, but I added this to the config

```
    logout:
        invalidate_session: false
```

Comment: if you use fos anyway ... why not using their build in features (login, logout, resetPassword, double opt in ...) and just styles them to your needs ?

The FOS Login considers the enabled flag of the user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. Symfony has already built-in mechanism to achieve that:

1. Implement [`AdvancedUserInterface`](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/AdvancedUserInterface.html) for your `User` class.
2. ...and that's it. For more, read http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#forbid-inactive-users

Comment: For some reason I had named my function 'getIsActive' (probably from some old documentation) which is why it wasnt working. Renamed it to 'isEnabled' and now FOS works catches it as expected, thanks