# Symfony: Override FOSUserBundle Resetting Controller

Tags: symfony, controller, overriding, fosuserbundle, reset-password

I'm trying to override the Resetting Controller of the FOSUserBundle. My own UserBundle is overriding the whole bundle, and it's working fine for e.g. templates but it's the first time I try to override a Controller and it seems like I'm doing something wrong.

Trying it that way (only copying in the first line since the rest of the controller is still the default one):

```
namespace UserBundle\Controller\User;

use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ResettingController as BaseController;
...


class ResettingController extends BaseController{
...
```

The "Reset Password" button is located on my login page.

What I'm trying to achieve is some customization for the **checkEmailAction**. I want to check whether the person who's requesting the password reset is a "locked" user or not, and also send a correct "Response Message" for each request. The rest of the Controller can stay the same.
I added some dumps and a "die;" into the code to check if there's any output but there is none.

Where do I best start looking? According to the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html I shouldn't have to be more than I'm already doing.

Comment: Did you set `FOSUserBundle` as parent of your `UserBundle`?

Comment: Yes, I did in my UserBundle class it says
public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }

and like I said, overriding templates works fine..

Comment: Are any other of your bundles a child of FOSUserBundle?

Comment: No, my UserBundle is the only child!

Comment: what is your resetting:
        token_ttl: in config.yml value ?

Comment: @JassonRojas it's 0 
is that wrong?

Comment: @sonja its ok, maybe you can implement the oiverride via routing:

fos_user_resetting_reset:
    path:     /resetting/reset/{token}
    defaults: {_controller: AcmeUserBundle:Resetting:reset }

Comment: @JassonRojas
I added it: fos_user_resetting_reset:
    path: /resetting/request
    defaults: { _controller: UserBundle:Resetting:request } and just to check the first page, I used the "request" part and added an "exit;" to my requestAction() but it doesn't go into my Controller again..

Comment: damn. you do clear cache ?. and how you define the fos_user routing in your routing.yml ?

Comment: @JassonRojas Yes, I cleared the cache like 100 times :D
hmm so far it's only
fos_user:
    resource: "@UserBundle/Resources/config/FOSUserBundle.xml"

Comment: @JassonRojas 
any further ideas? :/

Comment: @Forer sorry, I forgot to notifiy you when I answered your question. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @dlondero same for you, sorry I forgot to notify you!

Comment: Hi @sonja sorry for the delay D:.  The answer suggested for dlondero works for you ? or you still having the problem ? if you still have the problem i recomend you to share us an gits to know more about your problem. Thanks

Comment: I eventually solved it, it was a minor typo that caused it.. and no, the namespace is correct the way I posted it :)

Comment: You should post the solution then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My solution:
my mistake was in the routing.yml file. I first had:

```
fos_user_resetting_reset: path: /resetting/request defaults: { _controller: UserBundle:Resetting:request }
```

But I never actually wanted to override the request method and also the name Fos_user_resetteing_reset didn't match with **request**.

So my final solution:

```
fos_user_resetting_send_email:
    path: /resetting/send-email
    defaults: { _controller: UserBundle:User\Resetting:sendEmail }
fos_user_resetting_check_email:
    path: /resetting/check-email
    defaults: { _controller: UserBundle:User\Resetting:checkEmail }
```

this way I'm only overriding these two methods and the rest of the Resetting controller still picks up on the default one. :)